# LUIS Portal Display Issue

Tags: bots, azure-language-understanding

From time-to-time I run into display issues in the LUIS portal when looking at the utterances against some of my intents. Some utterances display as blank. When I first load this screen, the utterance displays as expected, but then the text disappears and it will only reappear later on, of its own accord.

Please advise how to resolve this.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4MEx.png)

Comment: This actually looks like a bug from Microsoft's end. I too faced this couple of days before when LUIS UI got changed. Did you tried writing to their support?

Comment: This isn't one we're currently tracking, so if you can give us any data to help reproduce it I'd appreciate. From your description, browser might be of import, along with whether the utterance disappears during the session, or across sessions, etc.

Comment: I have been unable to consistently reproduce this. I use IE11 to access luis.ai and it appears to be in a particular session.